# CSS Responsive video

Tags: html, css, video, responsive-design

Ive got a video embedded on our site as the header - Its looks fine in full screen but when i resize or view on a mobile it doesnt display correctly and gets big white gaps above and below. Can anyone help?

Site URL: http://www.petsubjects.co.uk/dev/index.html

```
<div id="ht-top-area">

    <div id="styled_video_container" class="videocontent1">
    <video width="2000px" position= "relative" autoplay loop>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Good point, ill remember to do this in future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, couple of things:

1. The Display:flex; is causing a broken look on my browser (you may want to look into displays, but it doesn't like you need flex here, just try display:block; for the video).
2. You have code which is specifically adding padding to the top/bottom arround line 3337:

---

```
#ht-top-area {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 180px 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great, but I still have a small amount of white space at the bottom of the video when I resize the browser, any ideas?

Comment: Indeed - the HTML under the video needs removing or set to display:none on smaller screens (class="ht-top-content").

Also, you need to set display:block; on your video (inline-blocks naturally have some small white space around them, this is separate to padding/margin).

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
<video position="relative" autoplay="" loop="" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;">
```

Comment: This solves the flexing issue, but not the mobile device "white-gaps" issue - these are being applied by padding in css.

Answer (score 0):

```
video {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}

#ht-top-area {
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0; //set this to 0 using a media query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of responsiveness problems in here. When you try to make something to look good don't think just about looking good in the screen that you are working. I suggest you use this css for the `ht-top-area id` at first (delete your own).

```
#ht-top-area
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And than this one:

```
video, audio {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

And for the video tag take of the fixed width that you have placed:

```
<video position="relative" autoplay="" loop="">...</video>
```